# Uncheck view protected range from Google Apps Script macro

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet with a protected range. The data is hard to read because of the hash marks. I can fix the problem manually by unchecking "Protected Range" in the view menu. Can I do the same thing from a macro?

Answer (score 1):

Bad news, I'm afraid.  I just spent an hour searching for the same answer myself, and I don't think there is one!

Workaround:  Include an image with screenshotted text that tells them to goto View > Protected Ranges.

Or just trust them not to frig with your sheet.  You can always rollback history.

Answer (score 1):

It is what it is.

From the [documentation](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=63175):

> Collaborators who try to edit a cell in a protected range they don’t
>   have edit access to will receive an error message. When opening a
>   spreadsheet with protected ranges, individuals will see ranges they
>   don’t have edit access to displayed with a checkered background.
>    **If the background pattern makes it difficult to read spreadsheet
>   content, you can hide protected ranges by pointing your mouse to the
>   View menu and unchecking Protected Ranges.**